# change old php page to redirection to asp.net page url using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have more than 100 page URL link is on `PHP` URL. And I want that when anybody enters my old URL it will be redirected to my specific URL for e.g:-
Old URL:-

1) www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=164&Itemid=171

2)www.abc.com/product-portfolio/disc-harrows/76

if user clicks on old url it will be moved permanently to 
New Url:

1) www.abc.com/product-portfolio/bale-spear/bale-spear

2) www.abc.com/product-portfolio/harrows/high-speed-disc-harrow

I use multiple methods but some url is find and some url is not found:- here is my code

```
    string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().ToString();
```

```
if(currentUrl.StartsWith("www.abc.com/product-portfolio/disc-harrows/74"))
```

`{
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "www.abc.com/product-portfolio/power-harrow/power-harrow");
        Response.End();
    }`

Comment: Do you mean `return Redirect("http://www.google.com");` This should be added as a return value to your method.

Comment: pls check 1st and 2nd point i want is somebody hit 1 url it will redirect automatically to 2nd url in asp.net